# how to see adb devices on linux container when host is windows 7 machine

Tags: docker, adb, docker-for-windows

i have a **windows 7** machine with docker tool box installed

i downloaded image and running container which have adb installed in it from below link

https://hub.docker.com/r/muicoder/adb/

The container is up and running, with container id mentioned below

```
9ba51613a7be
```

on my **host machine(windows 7)** , i have **nexus 6**  connected and i can see the result with

```
adb devices


> C:\Users\panmishr>adb devices List of devices attached
> * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
> * daemon started successfully 
> * ZY2235CQ26      device
```

i killed the **adb daemon**  in local host machine with

```
adb kill-server
```

Now i am trying to check the devices on container with below command, however it is not showing any devices mapped to container.

```
$ docker exec -it -d --privileged -P -p 5037:5037 9ba51613a7be adb devices
```

> List of devices attached

Kindly suggest what i am missing

Comment: Have you tried linking your docker port to your host's, like so : `-p 5037:5037` ?

Comment: did not work with -p either

Answer (score 0):

Just to add conclusion of this question.

Till date,I was not able to find a feasible solution to run windows docker on windows 7 machine. Most of the posts have been around windows docker with windows 10 and windows 2016 Server.

I switched to Linux docker on  windows 7 machine, However the **adb devices** were still not recognized on Linux container

Lastly , i had to go for Linux host and Linux Container and the devices were visible on container.

Answer (score 0):

`-p 5037:5037` is for seeing devices whis is running on container when typing `adb devices` on the host. But you would see devices connected on the host when you type `adb devices` in the container. For this

1. Install ssh server on your host which is win 7 then from your container forwarding the port 5037. Run like:

`$ ssh -T -N -L5037:127.0.0.1:5037 root@host.ip` host.ip may be: `192.168.0.10`

2. install ssh server on your container but first expose the container port 22 mapping 5022 on your host. (After configuring your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file). Run like:
   `$ ssh -T -N -R5037:127.0.0.1:5037 root@127.0.0.1 -p 5022` in your host for remote forwarding.

Before one option of two, you shoul map the port 8081 on your host like: `-p8081:8081`

So you just need to run:

```
docker run -p8081:8081 android_container
```

then

```
docker exec -it 9ba51613a7be adb devices
```

if you forwarded ports.

**You have also another solution** for this. Please check this repo: [RN-Container-with-ADB-Real-Device](https://github.com/inceabdullah/RN-Container-with-ADB-Real-Device)