# Connect to android emulator on host from docker container

Tags: android, docker, flutter, adb, emulation

I cannot connect to android emulator from inside of the container

I've already tried running the docker with command :

```
docker run --name test --network=host --privileged -p 5555:5555
```

And also with exposing -p 5037:5037.

Then typing in the container : 
adb devices

And I get no devices listed.

When I run adb devices from shell i get:

```
emulator-5554
```

When trying to :

`adb connect` 127:0.0.1:5555 or 0.0.0.0:5555 i get connection refused 
and `adb connect` 127.0.0.1:5037 or 0.0.0.0:5037 i get connection refused and after typing `adb devices` i get `offline`

Comment: Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865721/how-to-see-adb-devices-on-linux-container-when-host-is-windows-7-machine/60849146#60849146), then try **SSH port forwarding**

Answer (score 0):

Inside a docker container, you can use this following command

```bash
adb -H host.docker.internal devices
```

And you will see the list of devices in your host machine