# Can't connect to host ADB from within docker container

Tags: docker, networking, adb

Before this is my scenario an illustration of my environment to better understand my problem

[image]

I have a docker container running in my machine with the following `docker-compose` configuration

```
services: 
  addb-client:
    build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 19000:19000
      - 19001:19001
      - 19002:19002
    tty: true
    volumes: 
      - ".:/code"
```

From my `host` I execute the following command

```
adb -a -P 5037 server nodaemon
```

And I go the following output

```
adb I 01-12 11:06:05  2493  2493 auth.cpp:437] adb_auth_init...
adb I 01-12 11:06:05  2493  2493 auth.cpp:412] adb_auth_inotify_init...
adb I 01-12 11:06:05  2493  2499 transport.cpp:295] emulator-5554: write thread spawning
adb I 01-12 11:06:05  2493  2498 transport.cpp:282] emulator-5554: read thread spawning
adb I 01-12 11:06:05  2493  2493 transport.cpp:1373] fetching keys for transport emulator-5554
adb I 01-12 11:06:05  2493  2493 auth.cpp:489] Calling send_auth_response
adb I 01-12 11:06:05  2493  2493 adb.cpp:114] emulator-5554: offlin
```

Then from within my docker `container`, I run

```
adb connect yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

> yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy being my android emulator address as in the picture

```
failed to connect to 'yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:5555': Connection timed out
```

**But I got timeout**

I tried

```
adb connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

But I got `connection refused`

Note:

1.Commands such as , from within the container

```
adb -H yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy devices
```

Works well.

I will appreciate any helps you can provide me. If any additional information is needed please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: are you running `adb -H yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy devices` from the docker container?

Comment: @Lino yes that is correct

Comment: Any solution? I have the same problem :/

Comment: Yes I can post in a couple of hour but I dont think is worth it

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a networking issue....
To access the host from within the docker container, you have 2 options:

1. Access the ip of the docker bridge interface on the host

   ```
   $ docker run -ti busybox /bin/sh
   / # netstat -rn | grep ^0.0.0.0 | awk '{print $2}'
   172.17.0.1
   / # nc -vz 172.17.0.1 5037
   172.17.0.1 (172.17.0.1:5037) open
   ```
2. Add argument to the docker runtime to provide access from the container to the host via the 'localhost' keyword

   ```
   $ docker run -ti busybox /bin/sh
   / # nc -vz localhost 5037 ### NOT WORKING

   $ docker run -ti --net="host" busybox /bin/sh
   / # nc -vz localhost 5037
   localhost (127.0.0.1:5037) open  ### WORKING
   ```

The docker-compose equivalent is :

```
network_mode: host
```

Comment: I tried network_mode: host but for some reason, the project didn't start. FYI I'm trying to run expo

Comment: How do I find the "Access the ip of the docker bridge interface on the host"

Comment: see updated answer, try checking with simple busybox container

Comment: interesting, if I execute the first set of commands using the busybox it said that the port is open, but if I do the same inside my container it throws this error "192.168.240.1: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host" 192.168.240.1 is the output of the first command inside my container

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution that works for me is to use the `-H` option of the `adb` command with the value `"host.docker.internal"` which is a special DNS name resolved by Docker. For example, if you want to list all available devices by using `adb` in a container, use this:

```
adb -H host.docker.internal devices
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get devices list typing `adb devices` on your host, and if you want to get the same list running the same command in the console on the container, I would give an advice trying **port forwarding with ssh** .

Please inspect [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865721/how-to-see-adb-devices-on-linux-container-when-host-is-windows-7-machine/60849146#60849146) or this [repo](https://github.com/inceabdullah/RN-Container-with-ADB-Real-Device).